# Properties of $ f(k) =\int_0^k \frac{3+\sin(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to prove that $ f(k) =\int_0^k \frac{3+\sin(x)}{1+x^2}dx$ is strictly monotonically increasing and bounded by $2 \pi$ .

My idea was to show that $f'(x)$ is non-negative in the given interval $[0, k]$, but somehow I am stuck with that. Also I noticed that $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = arctan'(x)$, but I don't know how to make use of this.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**: My prove that $f'(x)$ is non-negative :
$\frac{3+\sin(t)}{1+t^2} = 0$

$3+\sin(t) = 0$ , since $ -1 \le\sin(t) \le 1$ no t exists which fulfills this equation.

Comment: I think you meant to write $f(k)$, since $x$ is the integration variable.

Comment: this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** 1) Our integrand is positive;

2) Our integrand is $\le \frac{4}{1+x^2}$.

**Remark:**  If you really want to use the derivative (with respect to $k$) to prove increasingness, use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. No manipulation is needed to show that $3+\sin x$ is positive, since $\sin x\ge -1$.